# Как реализовать выполнение SQL скриптов во время поднятия проекта?

Tags: java, sql

Всем привет, как настроить автоматическое выполнение SQL скриптов во время поднятия native Java проекте?

Comment: Какого рода проекта? Обычный запускаемый (например, через консоль), Tomcat, Spring или что-то ещё?
Какого рода скрипты? Они должны выполнятся всегда, или только если не выполнялись (успешно) в предыдущем запуске?

Comment: Посмотреть в сторону liquibase?

Comment: @AlekseiGaile слышал про него но не использовал, на сколько это может быть сложно для быстрой настройки?

Comment: @MikhailIonkin это обыкновенный проект с запуском через консоль. Скрипты типа `Create table if not exist`, то есть генерация схем, возможно какое то базовое наполнение.

Comment: @ВладиславПостоян, если немного разобраться то ничего сложного.

Comment: @AlekseiGaile оставь тогда это как ответ пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для таких целей можно использовать Liquibase.

По требованиям трудящихся ссылки на туториалы:

https://habr.com/ru/post/460377/

https://habr.com/ru/post/460907/

Comment: А примерами дополнить документацией ссылками и прочим не вариант